# Why cannot I upgrade?

Tags: 9, composer

I'm currently working on upgrading a Drupal site from Drupal 8.9.7 to Drupal 9.

I'm getting this error when I run `lando composer require "drupal/core:^9.3.8" --with-all-dependencies`.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Root composer.json requires overtrue/phplint ^0.2.4 -> satisfiable by overtrue/phplint[0.2.4].
> - drupal/core-recommended[9.3.8, ..., 9.4.x-dev] require symfony/yaml v4.4.34 -> satisfiable by symfony/yaml[v4.4.34].
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/yaml v4.4.34 (conflict analysis result)
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^9.3.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.3.8, 9.3.x-dev, 9.4.x-dev].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

The content of the *composer.json* is the following.

```json
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "composer/installers": "^1.7",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.9",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.4",
        "drupal/bamboo_twig": "^5.0@alpha",
        "drupal/console": "^1.9.7",
        "drupal/core": "^9.3.8",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.3.8",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.3.8",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.3.8",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.7",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.1",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.9",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
        "drupal/menu_trail_by_path": "^1.1",
        "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/panels": "^4.3",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.13",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.9",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
    },

    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "3.*",
        "behat/mink": "~1.7",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.2",
        "drupal/coder": "^8.2.12",
        "drupal/drupal-extension": "^3.1",
        "drush-ops/behat-drush-endpoint": "^0.0.4",
        "jcalderonzumba/gastonjs": "~1.0.2",
        "jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver": "~0.3.1",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "~1.2",
        "overtrue/phplint": "^0.2.4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^3.4.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": false,
            "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": false
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really at a loss at this point any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not normal to depend on `drupal/core` itself in Composer, because it is included by `drupal/core-recommended`. That could be the issue.

Comment: @cilefen I followed steps 1-3 here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later and now I get this error:

Problem 1
    - drupal/core-dev[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.x-dev] require symfony/css-selector ^4.4 -> found symfony/css-selector[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.4.0).
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-dev ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-dev[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.x-dev].

Updating to symfony/css-selector:^4.4 causes additional new errors.

Comment: Why are you installing Drupal/core-dev?

Comment: You can try for hours to repair the composer.json or simply download the current recommend Drupal 9 project and require the few extensions you have installed. Should take a few minutes to replace the codebase and you are ready to update the database.

Comment: @4uk4 I'm thinking this might also be a great option seeing that it's not a massively complicated site.

Answer (score 1):

> but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.4.0).

Yes, because `^` will never auto upgrade library to the next major version.

^3.4.0 is equivalent to saying >=3.4.0 < 4.0.0

So change it to `"symfony/css-selector": "^4.0.0"` in your composer.json

Comment: Thank you for explaining the composer ... operators? to me a bit more. It's definitely helpful. I'll try this as well.